# React on page reload receive error TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

When I land on a react page that I have created called"feedback," then I see the page display as expected.

However, if I go to refresh the page I receive an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

How can I resolve this issue?

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react"; 
import UserContext from "../context/UserContext"; 
import axios from 'axios';


const Feedback = () => {
    
    const { userData } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [review, setReview] = useState([]);

    const filtersActive = () => {
        setFilterMode(false); 
    }

    axios   
    .get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?email=${userData.user.email}`, userData)
    .then((response) => {  
        console.log(response)
        setReview(response.data)
    });

    return(   
            <div className='testing1234'>
                {review.map(review => (
                    <p key={review._id}>{review.review}</p>
                ))}
            </div> 
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only make the request if the property user in userData is defined.

You can add a useEffect which will be executed on userData changes then make the request, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userData.user) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?email=${userData.user.email}`)
  }
}, [userData]);
```